# Error in WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I am writing a program in Selenium, but getting error like below

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup;  "The method setup() is undefined for the type Object.
```

How to define setup() in `WebDriverManager.chromedriver` ! could you please help me out on this.

I downloaded `WebDriverManager` and `Chromedriver` and I added in `pom.xml` dependency.

But still getting error on
`WebdriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`
`WebDriverManager.chromedriver()` working fine.
When I entered `WebdriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` then its showing error. .

**Edit**:
Below is the code snippet
package org.h2k.openmrs.tests;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BaseClassExample {
    
    protected WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void instantiateDriver() 
    {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/login.htm");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Title of the page:::" + title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code into the question?

Comment: Hi Shawn,  
I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.create()` like:

```
WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver();
driver = wdm.create();
```

Then:

```
driver.get("https://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/login.htm");
```